# How can I load a property name from a plist?

Tags: objective-c, json, plist

I'm loading data from a piece of JSON into an object. I'm looping through the NSDictionary of the JSOn and find that I'm writing a nasty ladder of ifs, like this:

```
 if ([item isEqualToString:@"SiteName"]) {
 site.siteName = key[item];
 }
 if ([item isEqualToString:@"SiteUID"]) {
 site.siteUID = key[item];
 }
 if ([item isEqualToString:@"Own"]) {
 NSNumber *num = key[item];
 site.isOwnSite = [num boolValue];
 }
 if ([item isEqualToString:@"CompetingOwnSiteId"]) {
 site.competingOwnSiteId = key[item];
 }
 if ([item isEqualToString:@"LATY_NUM"]){
 site.LATY_NUM = key[item];
 }
 if ([item isEqualToString:@"LONX_NUM"]) {
 site.LONX_NUM = key[item];
 }
```

That's not going to work for me - it's ugly and hacky - so I reckoned I could put the property name and the corresponding NSString into a plist, for example:

[image]

I can grab the contents of the plist into another NSDictionary, and so by looping through both I can map what's in the JSON with the right method name in the plist.

BUT......

I don't know how to get the property name to 'attach' to the site object. (Sorry for this very technical jargon...).  For example, I want to get the NSString *siteName* from the plist and want to somehow generate the equivalent of

```
site.*siteName* = key[@"SiteName"];
```

If you can understand this stream-of-conscious, can you help me?

Many thanks!
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html). I'm assuming `key` is meant to be that plist that contains a mapping of keys to property names. If so, here's the basic form of what you're looking for:

```
[site setValue: whatever forKey: key[@"SiteName"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the [JSONModel](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel) POD rather than plists.
You can find [here](http://www.jsonmodel.com/) the documentation and samples. It mentions `Data models that take care of: Input Validation, Type Casting, Class Cascading & more. Automatically.` which might save you some time in the near-future.
As mentioned on the Github page, [here](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-fetch-and-parse-json-by-using-data-models/)'s a step-by-step tutorial on "How to fetch and parse JSON by using data models" which is probably what interests you.

If you haven't worked with PODs before, [here](http://blogs.triffort.com/?p=309)'s a pretty straight forward tutorial on how to set it up.

I'm using it for the project I'm currently working on and I find it very easy to setup and use.

Comment: Thanks Alex, it looks super.